# What does postgres.exe -V actually do?

Tags: postgresql

To know the version of postgresql, we normally use the command

```
..pgsql\bin>postgres.exe -V
```

My question is, whether this command starts the PostgreSQL server or not to find out the version.

Comment: I tried it, but didn't find any task.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code:

```c
if (strcmp(argv[1], "--version") == 0 || strcmp(argv[1], "-V") == 0)
{
    fputs(PG_BACKEND_VERSIONSTR, stdout);
    exit(0);
}
```

So it just prints the version and exits. The server is not started.